# Confusion about Array<Any> and Array<Int>

Tags: swift3

Starting out with Swift3, and am confused by following:

```
var o1:Array<Any> = [1,2,3]
var o2:Array<Int> = [1,2,3]

print(type(of:o2))
print(type(of:o2[0]))
o2[0] += 1
print(o2[0])

print(type(of:o1))
print(type(of:o1[0]))
//o1[0] += 1
print(o1[0])
```

compile and run, I get:

```
Array<Int>
Int
2
Array<Any>
Int
1
```

If I uncomment that line, I get a compilation error "Binary operator += cannot be applied to operands of type Any and Int"

ok, so it seems that Swift recognizes that o1[0] is an Int but I can't += it, but can do it on o2[0]. Any insight here as to why Swift says the type is Int but then wont really honor that type?

Comment: Because the check is on the compile time, not runtime type. Which is why it's the compiler that's complaining at you. That's pretty much the essence of static typing.

Comment: `Array<Any>` tells the compiler you can put `Any`thing in the array, not all of `Any` support `+=`. But the typeOf of the contents is done at runtime and tells you the actual type of the instance you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ok, so it seems that Swift recognizes that o1[0] is an Int but I can't += it, but can do it on o2[0].

Not so. The Swift compiler sees `o1[0]` as an `Any`, not an `Int`. This is why you're getting the error; when you write `o1[0] += 1`, you're asking Swift to use the `+=` operator on an `Any` (`o1[0]`) and an Int (`1`), and Swift doesn't have any definition of the `+=` operator that takes those two arguments. Since operators are resolved at compile time, this means that even if the value actually is an `Int` at runtime, the compiler doesn't have a way to know that, so it can't know how to resolve the operator.

Comment: Ok, thanks Charles (and others). That clears it up. I can do the downcast of o1[] to an Int and then use its value and assign it back to o1[] to update it.

Comment: @DavidN or rather don't use any unless you really need to (for instance when creating JSON objects from Dictionaries, there is a justifiable need for using `Any`). However, when using `Any`, you "disable" pretty much all advantages of the static type system , so it's not advised to use it.

Comment: "Swift sees" I think it's important to distinguish between the compiler and the runtime, since that's what the question is fundamentally about. The runtime demonstrably knows the element in question is an  `Int`.

Comment: @pvg I typically think of the compiler when just referring to "Swift" on its own, since the language tries to do as much as possible at compile time with a relatively minimal runtime (at least compared to Objective-C, anyway). But fair enough; I've edited the answer.

Comment: So I was really working with an array that could contain ints and also arrays of ints, so thats where the Array<Any> came from (I just distilled it down to the above example in trying to get to the bottom of things). Is there a better way to express an array of [1,2,3,[4,[5,6]]] ?

Comment: You could use an enum with two cases, one of which has an `Int` as an associated value, the other of which has an array.